# How to Sync with Outlook and Google

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync

Recently, [Google dropped the support for their Google Sync service](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936). That program was regularly reading your Outlook calendar, parse it, and then modify your Google Calendar to match - effectively synchronizing. This was useful to me because it allowed me to share my professional calendar with whom I chose (namely, my wife).

Now I'm looking for an alternative or how to continue a sync using Outlook. Please note I'm not trying to show my online calendar in Outlook. I want to update my online calendar with whatever I have in my Outlook 2010 one.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Software recommendations are typically off topic here. So I edited your question to keep it on topic, hope this is OK!

Comment: Yes that is fine, I had mentioned it just to point out I did my homework before asking here :)

Comment: If this is not about sharing, does the calender have to be Google?

Comment: I know your earlier post said you tried Outlook connector (before my edit) but this should have worked: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx Scroll down to *Synchronize your Hotmail calendars into Outlook*

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party apps (like [Sync2](http://www.sync2.com/?pcode=803270342ci77)) that are out there but I have not used them. 
There isn't a great free option right now with Google sync going away.

Answer (score 0):

Use this fantastic, free and opensource tool: Go Contact Sync Mod (http://sourceforge.net/projects/googlesyncmod/).
I've been using it for over 3 years now and the new version adds Calendar sync, just in time when Google has sunset its own Google Calendar Sync.